# Limit OperationContract's parameter's length in WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, .net-4.0

Is it possible to set a maximum length of an array parameter in an OperationContract like this one:

`<OperationContract()> Function GetData(pToken As String, pData As MyType()) As ResponseStatus`

(Meaning pData couldn't be longer than e.g. 100 elements.)

I know I can achieve similar effect by setting proper binding attributes in the config, but I'm looking for something different (which also wouldn't be an if in the function's body ;)).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate inputs implementing interface IParameterInspector.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647875.aspx) is example.